# ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken on delete form Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a problem with Rails 4 and deleting multiple items in a database.

I am working on creating an email inbox and I would like to move an item into the "trash folder" and after that I want to redirect the user to the trash page, where he can delete the item from the database.

My code:

routes.rb

```
namespace :admin do
  resources :inboxes do
    collection do
      match 'destroy_multiple' => 'inboxes#destroy_multiple', via: ['post','delete']
      get 'sent'
      get 'trash'
    end
  end
 end
```

controller :

```
def destroy_multiple
  if params[:action] == 'trash'
    @del = Inbox.where(:id => params[:delete]).destroy_all
  else
    @del = Inbox.where(:id => params[:delete]).update_all(:folder =>'trash')
  end
  redirect_to admin_inboxes_path
end
```

And finally, my form (slim) :

```
= form_tag destroy_multiple_admin_inboxes_path, method: :delete, class: "multiple_delete" do
  input type="hidden" name="action" value = controller.action_name
  - @inboxes.each do |msg|
    - @username = msg.email.gsub(/([^.]+)@.+/, '\1').gsub(/[^0-9A-Za-z]/, ' ').split.map(&:capitalize).join(' ')
    tr class=(msg.read == 1 ? nil : 'unread')
      td.inbox-small-cells
        label.checkbox-custom.check-success
          = check_box_tag "delete[]", msg.id, false, class: "for_del", id: "delete_#{msg.id}"
          label for="delete_#{msg.id}" 
      td.inbox-small-cells
        i.fa.fa-star.inbox-started
      td
        a.avatar href="/fr/admin/inboxes/#{msg.id}" 
          span.bg-primary =@username[0]
      td.view-message.dont-show = @username
      td.view-message = msg.subject
      td.view-message.inbox-small-cells
      td.view-message.text-right = msg.created_at.strftime("%d/%m")
```

I can with this code successfully move mail to the "trash", but I cannot delete them from the database.

Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by "impossible"?

Comment: Any update on the status of this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the authenticity_token to your form. Try:

```
form_tag destroy_multiple_admin_inboxes_path, method: :delete, class: "multiple_delete", authenticity_token: true do
```

If you're working with a specific active record object, use `form_for` instead of `form_tag`, and the csrf field will automatically be built into the form by rails. However, this is a good time to be using `form_tag`.

The alternative solution is to change the config `config.action_view.embed_authenticity_token_in_remote_forms` to `false`, but this will make your site less secure, and it's better to just add `authenticity_token: true` to your `form_tag`.

[Here is the documentation on form_tag](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-form_tag)

Comment: hi, thanks for your answer, but is the same, i have the same message with "authenticity_token" on form or not. But it's strange because, if i move to trash, and directly go to the trash folder for deleting items it's not work, but if i refresh the trash page and re-submit the form, items are successfully deleted and i don't have error message.

Comment: Adding `authenticity_token: true` had no effect? Is that correct?

Comment: Add the the gems better_errors, and binding_of_caller. This will give you a terminal window in the browser when things fail, and it might tell you the exact line where things are failing. It's possible we're overlooking something in the controller, for example.

Comment: i don't no, i have restarted  my vagrant machine and it's working ! thank you :)